# Losing session after Login

Tags: java, authentication

I'm building an application that needs to login to a certain page and make a navigation. I can login, provided that the response contains a string that identifies it. But when I navigate to the second page, I can't see the page as a logged user, only as anonymous.

I'll provide my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PostTest {
    static HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    static String sessionId = null;
    private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);


            String data = URLEncoder.encode("txtUserName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(/*username*/, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("txtPassword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(/*password*/", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("envia", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8");

            connectToSSL(/*login url*/);

                    //throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            String resposta = "";
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                resposta += line + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println("valid login -> " + resposta.contains(/*string that assures me I'm looged in*/));

            connectToSSL(/*first navigation page*/);

            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void connectToSSL(String address) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
                    if(sessionId == null) {
                            sessionId = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
                    }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Any further information, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

In `connectToSSL`, you are opening a new connection each time. In second connection, it will not have any attribute from first connection.

You may want to set get some token/cookie value after fist login connection and use the same in subsequent calls by e.g.

After first connection:

```
      String sessionId = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
```

In subsequent connections:

```
     conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionId );
```

Comment: That's right, I see it now. How would I, then, change the URL my connection is currently?

Comment: Not sure, if I got your question right? If its about accessing the second URL, just do what you are doing **in addition of** calling `conn.setRequestProperty()` before you attempt to open the streams from the second connection.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but I got an exception telling me that I already have a connection opened.

Comment: You may want to close the first connection after printing the values. Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Sound strange. If you don't mind, can you please `add` the updated full code in your question and highlight the line of issue with comment in the line?

Comment: I did as you told, updating my question.

Comment: `if(sessionId == null) {
                            sessionId = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); 
                    }` is already initiating your connection and hence `conn.setDoOutput(true);` is failing (if connection is already connected(used), it fails with the `IllegalStateException`).  Move this(sessionId) code after `conn.setDoOutput(true);` and try. Sorry for delay in response.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache Commons project [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html).  It will help you do what you are trying to accomplish.  You need sometime much more complex than a URL class.  It needs to maintain a lot of information to go from one authentication request to subsequent authenticated requests.

Comment: I'll take a look, but now I'm curious about how would I change the url of the HttpsURLConnection. Thanks, altought.

Answer (score 0):

The site you're accessing probably uses cookies to identify logged in sessions.  You'll need to save cookies set on the first request and send them on subsequent requests.

If you're using HttpsUrlConnection, see [Cookie Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-cookie.html) and [java.net.CookieManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).  Another choice would be [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) which do cookie management by default.

Answer (score 0):

http is a stateless protocol.
to retain state( sessions) store the cookies received from the server.
`List<String> cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");`

send them to server in subsequent requests

```
for (String cookie : cookies) {
```

`//remove  expires and  path from cookie`

`String cookieValue=cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(';');`
   `conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie",cookieValue);`
`}`

`OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());`

`wr.write(data);`